# C# override in Finalize()

Tags: c#, overriding, finalize

```
protected override void Finalize()
        {
            try
            {
                this.FtcpSock.Close();
                this.FudpSock6800.Close();
                this.FudpSock6801.Close();
                this.FudpSock6802.Close();
                this.FudpSock6803.Close();
                this.FudpSock6804.Close();
                this.FudpSock6806.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Finalize();
            }
        }
```

I m getting this Error Message:

`Error  1   Do not override object.Finalize. Instead, provide a destructor.`

by the way, this is Original Code complied by third party company.
how to solve this problem? how to Finalize with override?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Code seem to be completely wrong as it looks like closing managed objects in finalizer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can edit the code, you can move the code to a destructor. For a form called 'Form1' the destructor would look like:

```
~Form1()
{
    this.FtcpSock.Close();
    this.FudpSock6800.Close();
    this.FudpSock6801.Close();
    this.FudpSock6802.Close();
    this.FudpSock6803.Close();
    this.FudpSock6804.Close();
    this.FudpSock6806.Close();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx

Answer (score 5):

As the message states, you shouldn't override `Finalize` directly but instead provide a destructor.  Ignoring that though the code has one other fatal problem

```
protected override void Finalize() {
  try { 
    ...
  } finally { 
    this.Finalize();
  }
}
```

This code will eventually lead to a stack overflow in the code.  It is recursively calling itself in a `finally` block and hence will just loop until you run out of stack space.  The code was likely meant to use the following instead

```
base.Finalize();
```

This will chain to the implementation of `Finalize` on the base type